# Requests to /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml causing TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel app that is getting a reasonable amount of traffic.

To more gracefully handle exceptions of the TokenMismatchException type (which tend to get thrown when the session lifetime expires and then a user submits a form), I have altered the render() method of the exception handler, as follows:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException){

        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error',"Sorry your session has expired please resubmit your request.");
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This is working fine for normal requests, and instead of throwing the exception, it sets a session flash message and redirects back to the requested page. However, I'm noticing lots of these exceptions still being thrown for the following request:

```
/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

I'm aware the above is something to do with Exchange, so it's probably not malicious.

What I'm confused about is a) why is this unrouted url triggering Laravel's CSRF protection and b) why is my updated handler not catching the exception?

I've tried adding a route for this url, and manually throwing a 404, but this hasn't helped.

What can I do to prevent these exceptions being thrown?

**Edit - stack trace as requested:**

```
2015-10-26 11:44:38] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(54): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/vhosts/sitedomain.com/public_html/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Can you please add the error trace dump for the url `/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` ?

Comment: @Mysteryos - sure, I've added a sample stack trace.

Comment: The error trace dump isn't informative. How can you be sure that this file is causing these errors? Looks like you are having session persistence issues.

Comment: There are no session issues - and my exception handler works correctly in the context of real requests in the app. These rogue requests to /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml are the only requests still triggering the exception.

Comment: A request to a file will not trigger a php error. Only an access to a web endpoint that roots through your `index.php` enable the possibility of triggering of the above error.

Comment: @Mysteryos - there's no such file on the server, so this request is being handled by Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution turns out to be relatively simple. It seems like it's Laravel's default behaviour to handle all post (and presumably put and delete...) requests, whether they are defined in a route or not.

So we can add an exception to this in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware $except array:

```
protected $except = [
    'autodiscover/autodiscover.xml'
]
```

After adding the above, my TokenMismatchException is no longer thrown.

Comment: Still weirded out. Imagine a malicious user attempting to access a non-existent file on your server through non-`GET` requests. Your log will be filled with CSRF errors.

Comment: @Mysteryos I agree completely - surely any requests to non-existent routes should be completely disregarded? The default behaviour for a request that doesn't exist, and is not a Laravel route, should be a 404.

Comment: They don't 404 because global middlewares are applied before a request is routed, see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9708

.Hoped onto this gem: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#report-method
You can exclude CSRF errors from being logged.

Comment: @Mysteryos Useful links, thanks. It's a shame that the only way to exclude these exceptions is globally, or via my method above. Ideally, I would only want to exclude these for all un-routed urls - as this might otherwise indicate an attack on the site.